# проверка двоичного дерева поиска на корректность

Tags: c, алгоритм

Имеется некое двоичное дерево поиска с нодами вида:

```
struct node {
    struct node *left;
    struct node *right;
    int value;
};
```

проверить его на корректность, т.е. все ли элементы из левых поддеревьев меньше текущего узла, а из правого - больше.

Я написал следующие ф-ции (в `main` вызывается только `walk`):

```
bool proverka_l (struct node *nNode, int be)
{
    bool rez = true;

    if (nNode->value >= be)
        return false;
    if (nNode->left)
        rez = proverka_l (nNode->left, be);
    if (rez && nNode->right)
        rez = proverka_l (nNode->right, be);

    return rez;
}

bool proverka_r (struct node *nNode, int be)
{
    bool rez = true;

    if (nNode->value <= be)
        return false;
    if (nNode->left)
        rez = proverka_r (nNode->left, be);
    if (rez && nNode->right)
        rez = proverka_r (nNode->right, be);

    return rez;
}

bool walk (struct node *nNode)
{
    bool rez = true;

    if (nNode->left)
        rez = proverka_l (nNode->left, nNode->value);
    if (rez && nNode->right)
        rez = proverka_r (nNode->right, nNode->value);

    if (rez && nNode->left)
        rez = walk (nNode->left);
    if (rez && nNode->right)
        rez = walk (nNode->right);

    return rez;
}
```

Но в случае, если дерево является вырожденным (для каждой ноды имеется только один потомок), то затраты времени оказываются слишком большими. Как ускорить проверку?

Comment: Алгоритмическая сложность этой проверки никак не зависит от структуры дерева вообще. Поэтому если в вашем случае вы наблюдаете зависимость от структуры дерева - это именно расходы от "тяжелой" реализации.  В данном случае я вижу какую-то странную двойную рекурсию по `proverka_` и по `walk`. Зачем это понадобилось? Все можно сделать за один проход по дереву.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Вы реализовали проверку слишком "буквально", т.е. для каждого узла дерева целиком проверяете его поддеревья на неравенство со значением в этом узле. Это очень нерациональный квадратичный (!) подход, который делает много проходов по одним и тем же узлам и много раз проверяет одно и то же, т.е. "генерирует больше тепла, чем света".

Другими словами, данный подход не пользуется транзитивными свойствами сравнения и расплачивается за это ужасной неэффективностью. Уже проверив, что `a < b` и `b < c`, ваш алгорим еще рвется "на всякий случай" проверить, что `a < c`, хотя никакой необходимости в этом нет.

Более разумные алгоритмы:

1. **Алгоритм снизу-вверх**
   Реализовать рекурсивную функцию, которая возвращает диапазон значений, хранящихся в [под]дереве. На обратном ходе рекурсии для каждого узла проверять, что диапазон значений левого поддерева целиком лежит "слева" от значения узла, а диапазон значений правого поддерева целиком лежит "справа" от значения узла. Если хоть где-то в дереве эти условия не выполняются - дерево составлено некорректно.

   ```
   bool get_and_check_tree_range(const struct node *root, int *lo, int *hi)
   {
     assert(root != NULL && lo != NULL && hi != NULL);

     *lo = *hi = root->value;

     if (root->left != NULL)
     {
       int left_lo, left_hi;
       if (!get_and_check_tree_range(root->left, &left_lo, &left_hi))
         return false;

       assert(left_lo <= left_hi);
       if (left_hi > root->value)
         return false;

       *lo = left_lo;
     }

     if (root->right != NULL)
     {
       int right_lo, right_hi;
       if (!get_and_check_tree_range(root->right, &right_lo, &right_hi))
         return false;

       assert(right_lo <= right_hi);
       if (right_lo < root->value)
         return false;

       *hi = right_hi;
     }

     return true;
   }
   ```

   Вызываем для корня `root`

   ```
   int full_lo, full_hi;
   if (root == NULL || get_and_check_tree_range(root, &full_lo, &full_hi))
     /* Все в порядке */;
   else
     /* Дерево не упорядочено */;
   ```
2. **Алгоритм сверху-вниз**
   Рекурсивно обходя дерево, в каждый узел "спускать" сверху требования на то, в каком диапазоне должны лежать значения соответствующего поддерева. То есть если мы приходим в узел со "спущенным сверху" диапазоном `[a, b]`, а значение в этом узле равно `c`, то в левое поддерево мы спускаем требование `[a, c]`, а в правое - `[c, b]`. Если хоть в каком-то узле значение `c` не лежит в пришедшем сверху диапазоне `[a, b]` - дерево составлено некорректно.

   ```
   bool check_tree_in_range(const struct node *root, int lo, int hi)
   {
     assert(lo <= hi);

     if (root == NULL)
       return true;

     if (root->value < lo || root->value > hi)
       return false;

     return 
       check_tree_in_range(root->left, lo, root->value) &&
       check_tree_in_range(root->right, root->value, hi);
   }
   ```

   Вызываем для корня `root`

   ```
   if (check_tree_in_range(root, INT_MIN, INT_MAX))
     /* Все в порядке */;
   else
     /* Дерево не упорядочено */;
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы избежать вырождения можно использовать деревья с балансировкой, например, [АВЛ](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%92%D0%9B-%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE) или [красно-чёрные](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D1%87%D1%91%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE).

Например, при вставке последовательности `[1,2,3,4,5,6]` в обычное двоичное дерево получится вот что:

```
+-1
  +-2
    +-3
      +-4
        +-5
          +-6
```

Обратная последовательность (`[6,5,4,3,2,1]`) построит такое "дерево":

```
+-6
  +-5
    +-4
      +-3
        +-2
          +-1
```

А вот что мы получим в обоих вариантах для АВЛ-дерева:

```
+-4
  |-2
  | |-1
  | +-3
  +-5
    +-6
```

И:

```
+-3
  |-2
  | +-1
  +-5
    |-4
    +-6
```

P.S. Вообще тут надо решать что интересней: проверка дерева на корректность (по сути операция одноразовая и не совсем понятно зачем она нужна в регулярной работе с деревом), либо накладные расходы на балансировку: *экспериментально выяснено, что одна балансировка приходится на каждые 2 включения и на каждые 5 исключений (wiki)*.

Comment: Алгоритм проверки правильности структуры дерева потребует `O(n)` операций независимо от структуры дерева. Можно сделать хуже (что удалось автору вопроса), но лучше сделать не получится.

Comment: @AnT, ну да, поправил первое предложение, про вырожденность. И я таки не понимаю, какая разница сколько времени занимает  проверка корректности? Не вызывать же её в реальной работе постоянно. Куда интересней как быстро ищутся узлы...

Comment: Разумеется с точки зрения основной функциональности такая проверка бессмысленна. Только для QA и assert.

Comment: Я знаю как избежать вырождения - вот только вопрос не об этом.